# How to Add Objects into an Already Populated Array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, web-services

So I have an app that scans a UPC barcode and sends it to a web service called nutrionix. I get JSON data that I parse so that the user can see the ingredients in the scanned item on a table view. I want the FIRST CELLS meaning the first objects in the array to be the name of the item and the brand. I have defined the name of the item and brand like so:

```
    NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    _itemName = dataDictionary[@"item_name"];
    _brandName = dataDictionary[@"brand_name"];
```

As for my table view, I use an array that is sorted from another array. It's hard to describe so I'll just post the code for that as well:

```
 goodArray = [ingredientsString componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];


sortArray = [goodArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Now, "sortArray" is the array that is populating my Table View. It is a list of ingredients separated my commas. How can I add my itemName and brandName objects to make sure they're at the top of the table view?

All help is appreciated,

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-componentsSeparatedByString:` returns an immutable array. If you want to add something to the array, you'll need to make a mutable copy to which you can add the objects:

```
sortArray = [sortArray mutableCopy];
[sortArray addObjects:newObjectsArray];
```

Alternatively, you can create a new array by adding elements to the old one:

```
sortArray = [sortArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:newObjectsArray];
```